# PSR-0 SplClassLoader with many paths

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, spl-autoload-register, psr-0

After many hours, debugging, and modifying can't figure out if this is possible, please enlighten me.

My framework is used by many sites on my server. I'm trying to implement the [SplClassLoader](https://gist.github.com/221634) with little or no success. The loader working *(with some modify)* until i need to add another path *(when the dispatch done)*.

Looks like the loader can operate only when the framework is placed under the same directory the app sits in but not inversely.

Is it possible to use this loader with

- proper namespace support
- little or no hacks in it

when the library is centralized and many many apps will use it?

My setup:

```
/lib
  /Framework
    /Controller
      Front.php
/site1
  /App
    /App1
    /App2
      /Controllers
/site2
```

`site1/public/index.php` starts the Front Controller which doing the dispatch then starting the actual controller.

My (maybe wrong) namespace setup:

Every class inside of `Framework` using namespace `Framework`. This is fine until i want to start a controller which extending a class from the Framework. This is where thing are going wrong. The mentioned SplClassLoader can't handle paths like these. What i see from error logs is the main problem is `lib` isn't placed under `site1` which isn't acceptable for me.

Comment: You might be able to use symlinks to "include" your central directory "under" the current one.

Comment: Altough it'll probably do the job, it's definitely an unnecessary hack for me. Looks like i have some basic misunderstandings about namespaces. If i change them in my library i can go through dispatching without hacking the loader class. But the problem remains the same when i want to use a Controller which located elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Ok you didnt mention you were using PEAR naming/namespacing. In that case it works a bit differently.

First you need to adjust you class naming for the Framework. Those need a `Framework` segment so:

`Controller_Front`

should be

`Framework_Controller_Front`

This gives you a unique ns for the controller.

Then with the loader you would register a prefix like:

`$loader->registerPrefix('Framework', 'absolute/path/to/lib');`

No having never used the ClassLoader with PEAR naming im not sure you you need to leave a trailing `_` on the prefix or not but you should be able to figure that out with trial and error. Also Im not sure if you would point the path to 'absolute/path/to/lib' or 'absolute/path/to/lib/Framework' - again trial and error should point that out :-)

---

Ok not sure where you are going wrong but lets do this.

Lets make a file in `/lib` called `autoload.php` the contents being:

```
// require/use statements for the Symfony ClassLoader Component

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Framework' => __DIR__                    
));

$loader->register();

return $loader;
```

At this point the class loader is set up. So then in each site's index.php (or whatever you use to do your bootstrapping procedures:

```
// configure the path to the framework from SITE/public and require the autoload.php
$frameworkDir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../lib');
$siteDir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../'); // whatever gives us site1

$loader = require_once($frameworkDir . '/autoload.php');

// now lets start mapping our application specific namespaces
$loader->registerNamespace('App1', $siteDir . '/App/App1');
$loader->registerNamespace('App2', $siteDir . '/App/App2');

// then the rest of your bootstrapping and FC initialization
```

---

You might want to try the [Symfony Components ClassLoader](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/class_loader.html) - thats what i normally use. It shouldnt matter then as long as you are registering your namesapces with absolute paths.

```
$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Framework' => __DIR__ . '/lib',
    'AppOne'    => $somevarHoldingTheABSPrefixToTheAppOneCode . '/lib',
    'AppTwo'    => $somevarHoldingTheABSPrefixToTheAppTwoCode . '/lib',
    'AppTwo\\SomeVendor' => $somevarHoldingTheABSPrefixToTheAppTwoCode . '/vendor/somevendor/lib'                    
));

$loader->register();
```

Comment: Sorry but i can't get the idea: how can i call a class within the Framework, then later an AppOne? All i can get a lot of `Class not found` yet.

Comment: Well youll need to inject the loader instance into the application or have the application create it and then handle registering the framework. How to go abotu this is hard to say because you havent given any details on your set up. If you want to post more detail about how your applications are bootstrapped and where things live then i can give you more input.

Comment: +prodigitalson extended my question with details about my current setup, hope it clarifies the scenario.

Comment: tried as you wrote but the results are the same as before. Now it's sure it something wrong with my understandings of namespaces. What'll be the namespace of my Framework/Controller/Front.php if the class name is Controller_Front? How can i start it?

Comment: Oh, are you not using actual PHP Namespaces and using PEAR style instead?

Comment: nope, i'm using namespaces right now, but it seems, not properly. The actual namespace within the framework is `Framework`. That was fine with the previous class but not when i started a controller.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19944/discussion-between-prodigitalson-and-fabrik)